# The rate with which the coil intercepts the magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I came across this MCQ in my text book (question number 9) I thought the answer would be (a) but the correct one is (e), and I really don't get it, could you please explain it for me?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The coil will contain the greatest flux when the normal to the plane of the plane of the coil is at right angles to the magnetic field. The useful area of the coil will vary with the cosine of the angle between the field and the normal to the coil face. Take the derivative of the cosine and find the maximum rate of change of that useful, or projected, area. It is how fast you cut field lines that counts.